# About Mysql and Php and Forms

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I want to insert a + or - sign along with the database value in to the mysql while inserting from form in php? it should be added only in database but not in the form

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you done till now? Any code? You just need to concatenate whatever you want in your code, before storing into db

Comment: Well, its your code if you are fine with adding sign you can add them or don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to just add a + or - sign along with the value a user puts in a form?

You can either add a hidden section to your form and put the value in and add that to whatever you want, or you can add it in server side.

Client Side Form

```
<input type="hidden" name="Sign" value="-">
```